# PL/SQL function with in params and joins and if else

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have this `PL/SQL function` which takes the name of a student(emri) and a subject(lenda) and returns a status if the student passes is that subject or not. If the mark (nota) is greater than 4 the student passes and if it is 4 it doesn't.

If I remove my `select query` the function compiles with no error but when I compile with the select query it says: `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`

The query works fine when run alone, not in the function. What is wrong here? Thanks

```
create or replace function std_status(emri in varchar2, lenda in varchar2)
return varchar2

is

nota nota.nota%type;
status varchar2(20);

begin

select n.nota into nota
from studenti s
join nota n on s.ids = n.ids
join lenda l on l.lid = n.lid
where s.emri = emri and l.emri = lenda;


if nota>4 then
status := 'kalues';
else 
status := 'ngeles';
end if;

return status;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will cause your error, but using the same name for your variable, column and table seems like bad practice, and may well have something to do with your error, I would change them all to something different.